# whats is the error in ajax code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**jqlib.js is https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js**

> nothing is happing i m trying to add to number using ajax using jquery 3.2.1.js

**cant find the error in this code can anyone tell me where is the error in this code**

> add.php

```
<html>
 <body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqlib.js"></script>
    <form id="tt">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter first Number</td>
                <td><input type=text name=t1 ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter 2nd Number</td>
                <td><input type=text name=t2></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type=button value="OK" onClick="cal()"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Addition</td>
            <td><input type=text name=t3 id="tt1"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function cal()
    {
        var frm = $("#tt");

        $.ajax(
        {
            type:"POST",
            url:"ajax.php",
            data:frm.serialize(),
            sucess:function (data)
            {
                $("#tt1").val(data);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST))
{
if(($_POST['t1']!="" )|| ($_POST['t2']!=""))
{
    $z = $_POST['t1'] + $_POST['t2'];

}
else
{
    $z ="please enter data";
}
echo $z;
}
else
{
echo "please enter data";
}
?>
```

Comment: blank nothing is showing

Comment: check @SepehrRaftari 's answer

Comment: @AyushmanKasyap check SepehrRaftari's answer, and if it helps, upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

you have a typo error:
`sucess` should be `success`

Answer (score 0):

Change your script as follow and check whether any alert is showing or not

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function cal()
{
    var frm = $("#tt");

    $.ajax(
    {
        type:"POST",
        url:"ajax.php",
        data:frm.serialize(),
        sucess:function (data)
        {
            $("#tt1").val(data);
            alert('Success: '+data); ///---> this show alert with success and content
        },
        error:function(a,b,c)
        {
            alert(c); //---> If error happen it will show alert();
        }
    });

}
</script>
```

Comment: check your browser console. It will show any jquery error in it

Comment: @Fairy requesting a clarification from OP would be a fine comment methinks, but not answer material. Anyways, you also duplicated OP's typo.